# Concordance des temps dans « Si on m'apprenait que la fin du monde est pour demain »

Tags: concordance-des-temps, discours-indirect

> Si on m'apprenait que la fin du monde **est** pour demain, je planterais quand même un pommier.

Ne faut-il pas plutôt dire « Si on m'apprenait que la fin du monde **était** pour demain ... » ?

Answer (score 5):

On a une certaine liberté de choix à propos du temps à utiliser dans ce cas.

Le présent, l'imparfait, voire le futur (*que la fin du monde sera pour demain*) ou le conditionnel présent (*que la fin du monde serait pour demain*) se rencontrent.

Bien que l'imparfait de concordance paraisse plus conforme aux conventions, le présent semble le plus courant :

> C’est comme si on me disait que je ne suis pas le petit-fils de mon grand-père, parce qu’un collatéral, demeurant en Italie, s’était emparé de son testament et de mes titres.
>
> Voltaire, *Histoire de Jenni*, 1775.

Comment: Pourquoi on a le choix dans ce cas précis?

Comment: Comme l'a écrit Laure (+1), on rapporte dans ce type de phrase ce que quelqu'un d'autre a dit. On peut reprendre le temps utilisé par le tiers (ex: *c'est comme si on me disait que la fin du monde a eu lieu hier*) ou apporter son jugement sur la probabilité de l'événement futur via le présent ou l'imparfait.

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit ici d'examiner la concordance des temps dans le cadre de paroles rapportées (discours indirect).

Avec un verbe à l'imparfait (*on m'apprenait*) pour introduire le discours rapporté le choix entre le présent ou l'imparfait dans les propos rapportés est stylistique.

**Le présent** rend les propos plus proches et indique de la part du locuteur une croyance plus forte dans ces propos.

**L'imparfait** met de la distance entre le locuteur et les paroles rapportées ce qui  diminue sa croyance en une fin du monde pour demain.

À noter que la différence serait la même si le verbe qui introduit les propos rapportés était au présent (*si on m'apprend*...), et ça ne changerait rien sur le rôle de cette proposition comme subordonnée introduite par *si*.